# Weekly update the column in the same table for based on previous week calculations and

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to write a store procedure to weekly update the WeeklytotalHours column in the same table for previous week.
I have timeclock table which has fallowing items

```
TcEmployeeID Int
TcDate Date
ClockIn Datetime
ClockOut Datetime
TcTotalHours (Computed column calculated daily hours)
WeeklytotalHours
```

And I tried this query:

```
SELECT 
TcEmployeeID, MAX(TcDate) As LastClockInDate, 
(sum(TcTotalHours) / 60   + (sum(TcTotalHours) % 60) / 100.0) as WeeklytotalHours 
FROM tclock.TimeClock t2 
WHERE t2.TcEmployeeID=TcEmployeeID 
AND t2.TcDate=TcDate 
AND TcDate IN (
  SELECT TcDate 
  from tclock.TimeClock 
  WHERE TcDate BETWEEN DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7, GETDATE()),-1) AND DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7, GETDATE()),5)
) 
GROUP BY TcEmployeeIDcode
```

I am getting the results below. However how can I update the WeeklytotalHours column with the results of my query?

```
EmployeeId-----LastClockInDate-----WeeklyTotalhr           

      92000    2015-07-10       48.500000
      88000    2015-07-08       25.140000
      93000    2015-07-11       7.300000
```

Comment: I don't think that sql you posted is valid.

Comment: Also, is weektotalhours a running SUM(HOURS) by empid,yearnum,weeknum, or is it suppose to be the MAX(SUM(Hours)) for each empid,yearnum,weeknum?

Comment: Above query brings the max date of previous week Sunday through Saturday which employee clocked id wit the sum of totalhours. query is working . Example Employee clocked in and out whole week and each row is calcuated the totalhours in computed column for that day so employee 92000 clockout 2015-07-10 as last day in previous week is total hours for whole week is calculated correctly. I just need to update  WeeklytotalHours column for for above return results I need to update employee 92000 on 2015-07-10 WeeklytotalHours=48.50 and next row 88000 so on and so forth